# Looping through JSON (from google spreadsheet) using PHP

Tags: php, json, google-apps-script

I get the concept of using a 'for each' loop and outputting the results from the stored json object.

However, I'm totally stuck on applying the logic to the JSON that comes from a google spreadsheet.

Ideally what I'd like to do is loop through and only output values for gsx$text and gsx$url. I think I'm just having trouble targeting the array values correctly.

Thank you for any assistance!!

Here's as far as I've gotten with code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json&amp;callback=displayContent";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

//print_r ($data);

foreach($data as $item) {
    echo $item['feed']['entry']['gsx$text']['$t'];
    echo $item['feed']['entry']['gsx$url']['$t'];
}

?>
```

Here's the sample JSON from my google spreadsheet:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "feed": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
        "xmlns$gsx": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended",
        "id": {
            "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-04-04T16:14:33.594Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "Sheet1"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE"
            },
            {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values?alt=json"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "$t": "michael.daul"
                },
                "email": {
                    "$t": "michael.daul@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "openSearch$totalResults": {
            "$t": "2"
        },
        "openSearch$startIndex": {
            "$t": "1"
        },
        "entry": [
            {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values/cre1l"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2014-04-04T16:14:33.594Z"
                },
                "category": [
                    {
                        "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                        "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
                    }
                ],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "1"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "end: 5, text: this is a test entry, url: http://www.google.com"
                },
                "link": [
                    {
                        "rel": "self",
                        "type": "application/atom+xml",
                        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values/cre1l"
                    }
                ],
                "gsx$start": {
                    "$t": "1"
                },
                "gsx$end": {
                    "$t": "5"
                },
                "gsx$text": {
                    "$t": "this is a test entry"
                },
                "gsx$url": {
                    "$t": "http://www.google.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": {
                    "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values/chk2m"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "$t": "2014-04-04T16:14:33.594Z"
                },
                "category": [
                    {
                        "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                        "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
                    }
                ],
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "6"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "$t": "end: 10, text: this is also a test, url: http://www.yahoo.com"
                },
                "link": [
                    {
                        "rel": "self",
                        "type": "application/atom+xml",
                        "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AucrbcW2_KdddFR1ZmhaYmUwc0FtNm1uTV9pMGZTUUE/od6/public/values/chk2m"
                    }
                ],
                "gsx$start": {
                    "$t": "6"
                },
                "gsx$end": {
                    "$t": "10"
                },
                "gsx$text": {
                    "$t": "this is also a test"
                },
                "gsx$url": {
                    "$t": "http://www.yahoo.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `$data` is an array, so the `foreach` is not going to work. Examine the results of the `print_r` statement you have commented out - that's going to tell you how to refer to elements in `$data`.

Comment: Thanks Kryten - I think the problem was using the 'json-in-script' call from google instead of just 'json'; I've edited the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the array you want to iterate is

```
$data['feed']['entry']
```

so

```
foreach ($data['feed']['entry'] as $item) {
  echo $item['gsx$text']['$t'];
  echo $item['gsx$url']['$t'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop trough it if you access it that way.

```
echo $data['feed']['entry']['gsx$text']['$t'];
echo $data['feed']['entry']['gsx$url']['$t'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Libraries on GitHub. Dependencies are good :)

- **[php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client)** <<< (Composer + Tests)
- [google-spreadsheet-to-php-array](https://github.com/VernierSoftwareTechnology/google-spreadsheet-to-php-array)
- [google-doc-spreadsheet-parser-php](https://github.com/ssavajols/google-doc-spreadsheet-parser-php)
- [parseGData.php](https://gist.github.com/printminion/3898429)
- [showspreadsheet.php](https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/770584) (prototype)